# Does sleeping directly after eating cause permanent health issues?

Tags: nutrition, sleep

I've heard sleeping directly after eating makes digestion less effective, i.e. you don't get all the nutrients you could get if you would stay awake.
I've also heard it raises sugar levels in the blood.
But does it have any negative long term affects?